# The confusing cat

Tags: wordplay, no-computers, computer-science

I have a cat. The cat found a mouse. The mouse fled and found a keyboard. The keyboard was pressed by me and on the monitor appeared a 5-letter word with the 1st and 4th letters the same. Then the cat found the monitor. The cat ran and found this question and cats. What does the cat say afterwards?

Hint:

> One of the sentences can be parsed in two ways.

Comment: The five-letter words with first and fourth letters the same [488 words](https://quinapalus.com/cgi-bin/qat?pat=1..1.&ent=Search&dict=0). Now to narrow it down somehow?!

Answer (score 7):

The cat says

> MIAOW, as this sequence of events will not have changed the cats behavior. Cats can't read :)

Comment: Heh, why was this accepted for a couple of minutes?

Comment: It was my "other self", who thought it was the answer. Then I took over and undoed the accept.

Comment: @user_194421 Oh good, because this was (almost) a joke answer, that just happened to seemingly fit.

Answer (score 4):

It's broad again, at this point, but a shot in a dark.

The cat must have said

> **RETRY** :-) It will enjoy catching the mouse again.

Answer (score 1):

Based on:

> The keyboard was pressed by me and on the monitor appeared a 5-letter
>   word with the 1st and 4th letters the same.

I'm going to guess:

> **ENTER** - prompt to enter a password.